# single value change position & a new value enter in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

from my previous coding,

`m=zeros(3);
m(randi(numel(m)))=2`

i got as follows

```
0 0 0
0 2 0
0 0 0
```

where the number 2 appears randomly.

now i dont know how to change the random number position &
at the same time a new value 2 is entered

like example, i want to change the direction to the right side &
the expected value is

```
0 0 2
0 0 2
0 0 0
```

or something like that~

where the first value 2 go to the right side position & a new value randomly enter anywhere in the array

how should do it? 
i need advise..

Comment: You can use `find` to get the position of your moved elements and then `m_subset = setdiff(find(m), 1:numel(m)); m(m_subset(randi(numel(m_subset)))) = 2` to set a new location. Moving the old set number first depends on how you want to move it. If you want to move it randomly use `randperm`. If you want to move it specifically try `circshift`

Comment: like this??   **m_subset = setdiff(find(m==2), 1:numel(m)); 
m(m_subset(randi(numel(m_subset)))) = 2
p=circshift(m,[1 1])**

Comment: yes but use `circshift` first and then operate on `p` instead of `m`...

Comment: is that how to change the original number position?  `number= find(m);
m=circshift(number,[ ])` but using `circshift` require the coordinate.. what to put inside the `m=circshift(number,[ "??"])`

Comment: You haven't explained how you want to change the positions of the number that is already there, so how could anyone possibly answer you? You need to actually tell us what you are trying to do *exactly*. Also what was wrong with `m=circshift(m,[1 1])`?

Comment: i already solve that, now the problem is the new number is not appear `if (m>=7);
            m_subset = setdiff(find(m), 1:numel(m)); 
            m(m_subset(randi(numel(m_subset)))) = 2`   what did i do wrong?

Comment: after find the original m position, i put your code.. and the error appear is **Error using randi
First input must be a positive scalar integer value
IMAX, or two integer values [IMIN IMAX] with IMIN less
than or equal to IMAX.

Error in projek (line 39)
           m(m_subset(randi(numel(m_subset)))) = 2**

Comment: What was `numel(m_subset)`? If it's `0` then you've messed up.